# C# clickable grid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to create a game that has a grid and the user can click the grid areas to toggle their state. I am using WinForms. I can find 2 ways to do this, both seem complicated:

1. A table-layout-panel, and place a label or button in each area, and when the button is clicked, figure out (somehow) which column and row the click was in and act accordingly.
2. An unbound GridView.

Both seem very complicated to handle something like this.

For example, think of a tic-tac-toe game. All I want in this case is a 3x3 grid, and to know which area (x,y) was clicked and draw something in this area.

Comment: what have you done so far? show some code.

Comment: See here - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2400/Tic-Tac-Toe-in-C. Seems like he has used a Button Array.

Comment: Yes it's complicated Windows.Forms is not suitable for games. If you want to make more serious games check out XNA: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23714

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me show you something i have written that come closer to your needs, maybe:

```
    private Button button;
    private Dictionary<string, Image> images = new Dictionary<string, Image>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeTableLayoutPanel();
        AssignClickEvent();

        InitializeDictionary();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create Buttons for all Cells in the TableLayouPanel
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeTableLayoutPanel()
    {         
        for (int i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < tableLayoutPanel.RowCount; j++)
            {
                button = new Button();
                button.Visible = true;
                button.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

                tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(button, i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Assign a Click event of all Buttons in the TableLayoutPanel
    /// </summary>
    private void AssignClickEvent()
    {
        foreach (Control c in tableLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType<Button>())
        { 
            c.Click += new EventHandler(OnClick);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handle the Click event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Button</param>
    /// <param name="e">Click</param>
    private void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        button.Visible = false;

        int column = tableLayoutPanel.GetPositionFromControl(button).Column;
        int row = tableLayoutPanel.GetPositionFromControl(button).Row;

        InitializePictureBox(column, row);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create the PictureBox 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="column">TableLayoutPanel Column</param>
    /// <param name="row">TableLayoutPanel Row</param>
    private void InitializePictureBox(int column, int row)
    {
        PictureBox box = new PictureBox();
        box.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        string key = string.Format("{0}{1}", column.ToString(), row.ToString());

        box.Image = GetImageFromDictionary(key);

        tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(box, column, row);           
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get an Image from the Dictionary by Key
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">the calling cell by combined column and row</param>
    /// <returns>Image</returns>
    private Image GetImageFromDictionary(string key)
    {
        return images.Where(x => x.Key == key).Select(x => x.Value).Cast<Image>().SingleOrDefault();             
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add Bitmaps to the Dictionary
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeDictionary()
    {
        string key = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < tableLayoutPanel.RowCount; j++)
            {
                key = string.Format("{0}", i.ToString() + j.ToString());
                Image image = CreateBitmap();
                images.Add(key, image);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create Bitmaps for the Dictionary
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Bitmap</returns>
    private Bitmap CreateBitmap()
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap image = new Bitmap(button.Width, button.Height);
        for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
            {
                image.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);
            }
        }
        return image;
    }
```

Before Click:

[image: Before clicking the Button]

After Click:

[image: After clicking the Button]

Note that i've create columns and rows by designer, but i think it's nothing special to create them programmatically.

What could be the next steps?

1. Create various colored pictures
2. Create columns and rows of the panel programmatically
3. Build it more flexible by setup individual settings

Hope this helps a little bit.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this.

Answer (score 2):

Use a PictureBox and draw the grid lines yourself. You can do this for instance by registering the event Paint. Then register for the event [MouseClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick.aspx) to get location an details where the user clickes on the grid (on the PictureBox).